# SQL and iReport - Aggregate functions in the Where clause and Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, jasper-reports, ireport

Well basically I would like to be able to use a parameter on *iReport* with an aggregate function.
If you type "yes" it will show you the values greater than 0, if you type "no" it will show the values that are less than 0. However, the aggregate function first adds up all the values related to an id and then it subtracts the result from another value, the result of that is the one I want to show.

How would I be able to do this? I'm clueless as I don't know how to use it with *HAVING*.

Comment: can you post your sql query please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what 'it' refers to in "I don't know how to use it with HAVING." The question will be much clearer with some SQL. But I guess you're looking for this:

```
SELECT id, sum(values) as the_agg
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING sum(values) $P!{BiggerOrSmaller} 0
```

The default value for the parameter BiggerOrSmaller should be like this:

```
$P{MyParam}.equals("yes") ? ">" : "<"
```

This assumes you have a parmeter called `MyParam` which can take the value "yes". Based on that value it sets the parameter `BiggerOrSmaller` appropriately.

Comment: The HAVING clause cannot reference columns by aliases assigned in the SELECT clause. Some SQL products do extend the syntax to allow that, but SQL Server is not one of them.

Comment: Good point. I updated the SQL to not use the alias in the having clause.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as soon as I can